# Assign struct to multiple structure member

Tags: c, structure

I would like to initialize several members of a structure by assigning a "matching" structure to the members without explicitly assigning each member.

Here is an example to better explain it. I have two structures:

```
typedef struct
{
    void* ThingB;
    void* ThingC;
}SomeThings_S;

typedef struct
{
    void* ThingA;
    void* ThingB;
    void* ThingC;
}AllThings_S;
```

I would like initialize members ThingB and ThingC in AllThings_S by directly assigning Somethings_S to members ThingB and ThingC in AllThings_S. See the following:

```
void* ThingA;
void* ThingB;
void* ThingC;

SomeThings_S SomeThings =
{
    ThingB,
    ThingC,
};

AllThings_S AllThings =
{
    .ThingA = ThingA,
    SomeThings, <--- This is where I'm not sure how to proceed.
}
```

I can do the following:

```
AllThings_S AllThings =
{
    .ThingA = ThingA,
    .ThingB = SomeThings.ThingB,
    .ThingC = SomeThings.ThingC,
}
```

But this is what I'd like to avoid. I'd prefer if I can directly assign Somethings to ThingB and ThingC in AllThings.

Sorry. I had a hard time to trying and explain. Hope it is readable.

Comment: How about making `SomeThings` a sub-struct of `AllThings`?

Comment: You cannot. You *could* make `AllThings` have a `SomeThings` member. You could *try* making `AllThings` have a common prefix with `SomeThings`, and cast a pointer, but you're in pretty dire straits there, with UB lurking all around.

Comment: I was thinking of making Somethings a member of AllThings, but then I have to do all the member name typing when accessing the members. AllThings.Somethings.ThingB. I just want Allthings.ThingB without having to type the name of the member struct SomeThings.

Comment: Well, you could make a anonymous `union` with one anonymous `struct SomeThings`-member and a named `struct SomeThings`-member, so you can choose whether to access the members together via the named struct or individually and without intermediate member selection via the anonymous struct. However, whether this is well-defined may be an interesting language-lawyer question.

Comment: @EOF That is exactly what I was thinking. I never use anonymous unions or structures and that might exactly be what I was looking for. "Anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do this--and I want to stress that I really don't advise this--you can make use of the `-fplan9-extensions` or `-fms-extensions` option in gcc that allows you to access members of anonymous structs directly.  If using clang, use `-fms-extensions` as it does not have the plan9 extensions last I knew.

What it may look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void* ThingB;
    void* ThingC;
}SomeThings_S;

typedef struct
{
    void* ThingA;
    SomeThings_S;
}AllThings_S;

int main(void) {

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    SomeThings_S x = {&a,&b};
    AllThings_S y = {&c, x};

    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", y.ThingA, y.ThingB, y.ThingC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the comment from EOF by using an anonymous union and structure.